# Adding '\0' to end of non null terminated "string"

Tags: c

So I'm reading from a file into a buffer. By default, this method doesn't null terminate my string.

```
size_t result;
size_t total = 0;

/* Get the file size */
FILE* pfile; 
pfile = fopen(filename, "rb");
fseek(pfile, 0, SEEK_END);
long lfile = ftell(pfile);
rewind(pfile);

char* file_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * lfile);
while ((result = fread(file_buffer, 1, lfile, pfile)) > 0)
{
    total += result; 
}

resp->content_length = lfile;
file_buffer[lfile] = '\0'; //so I try to null terminate it here.
```

But I'm getting invalid write of size 1. What am I doing wrong?

Is there another way to null terminate what's in my buffer?

Comment: What do you mean by invalid write? BTW, you are allocating size `lfile` and you are trying to access a position outside it `file_buffer[lfile] = '\0'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your computation of the string length seems to be wrong in the call to `malloc`. You have to add `1` to account for the `0` character.

Edit: BTW, your use of `sizeof(char)` is ... useless. `sizeof` and `malloc` are just defined that they count things in the size of a `char`, so `sizeof(char)` will always be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`file_buffer[lfile]` is out of bounds, since `file_buffer` only has `lfile` elements. It's like saying `int x[1]; x[1] = 0;`.